# How do I create a space around special characters in python?

Tags: python, string, math

This is what I want the code to do:

```
string = "1+1+1"

#insert code here

output:
>>>1 + 1 + 1
```

Basically I'm trying to create a " " around the special characters. (In this case it's the plus signs)

Comment: Have a look at the Unicode character category of *Space Separator*s and choose one you like.  I presume that you know how to include Unicode characters into your strings, if you don't, add that into your question.

Comment: For multiple special characters, translate should be a good method: `string.translate({ord(ch): f' {ch} ' for ch in special})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above string you can try this as there is only one special character

```
print(' + '.join(S.split("+")))
```

or

```
print(S.replace("+"," + "))
```

If you have multiple of them then try something like

```
result = ""
for char in string:
    if char in special_chars:
        result += " "+char+" "
    else:
        result += char
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split them first, and then re-join them

```py
special_char= '+'
string= "1+1+1".split(special_char)
string= f' {special_char} '.join(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to better define special characters.
But anyway the solution is to .split() the string and then .join() it like that:

```
my_string = "1+1+1"    
delimiter = '+'
my_string = f' {delimiter} '.join(my_string.split(delimiter))
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment here is example for multiple delimiters:

```
my_string = "1+1-1"
delimiters = ['+', '-']
for delimiter in delimiters
    my_string = f' {delimiter} '.join(my_string.split(delimiter))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add multiple delimiters?

Comment: Hey, Sure, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```py
import re
string = "1+1+1"
print(re.escape(string).replace("\\"," "))
```

Here the output that i got

```
1 +1 +1
```